# Solar Inverter makes 15kHz noise at ~70dB when running

Tags: noise, inverter, solar-energy

I have a solar power setup with an array of panels running to an inverter, which is connected to a set of batteries and to two other devices for monitoring the net metering, power output, and so on.

When the inverter is receiving power from the panels and is inverting it, there is a 15kHz whine/scream from the inverter. It's unbearably loud to me and my wife, but 15kHz is high pitched enough many people can't hear it.

Further - I have 2 appliances from LG that are "smart inverters": a microwave and a washing machine. When the inverter runs, these appliances also emit the exact same 15kHz screech and it's unbearably loud inside. Other appliances like my computer monitors, cable modem, hue lightbulbs, audio receiver ALSO make the 15kHz noise, but not to the degree of the LG microwave.

We have tried:

- Disconnecting the batteries such that it's a simple solar setup
- Changing settings on the inverter to various power settings per the manufacturer's advice
- Adding toroids to the battery cables - this caused a spreading of the 15kHz spike into a more spread out curve from 14kHz to 16kHz, but didn't really change the ear splitting effect. When we did this, the devices inside also spread out their screech.

The inverter is a Sol-Ark 12kW. I don't know much about electronics, but here's a spec sheet: https://www.sol-ark.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/12K-Spec-Sheet-2-4-2021.pdf

I've read that more economic manufacturing processes will reduce cost in ways that increase noise production. This came up as I read about [FCC 15 class B](https://www.fcc.gov/oet/ea/rfdevice) for unintentional radiators. But in reading the specs for the upper sonic range (10kHz-20kHz), I don't know how to approach measuring to see if my inverter meets the spec. The product itself has been confirmed as compliant with that regulation, so my question is more... Is it something in my house causing this?

Another thing to note: WHILE the washing machine runs, when the motor turns the basin, the noise spikes at 15kHz regardless of the inverter running or not. If I then muffle the sound and put my spectral analysis app on my microwave, I can see the 15kHz pulsing when the motor from the washing machine pulses.

These noises are essentially inaudible if the inverter is not running, but at this point I'm 6+ months into a worthless solar installation that I'm paying for because when it runs I have ringing in my ears 24/7 and nonstop headaches.

From an electronics standpoint - does anything stand out? Am I overlooking something? Is there a standard way to get electricians/installers to take this seriously if they themselves can't hear the noise?

Comment: *I've read that more economic manufacturing processes will reduce cost in ways that increase noise production* And that's the main issue, the ~15 kHz is a compromise to get the cost down. The manufacturer probably can't meet the cost and effciency (which is important to many customers) with a design operating above 15 kHz and/or a design that is quieter. *I don't know how to approach measuring to see if my inverter meets the spec.* For that you will probably need expensive equipment and also experience to measure that under the right conditions.

Comment: At least for the solar inverter, keep it *outside* the house or in an infrequently used room. Diesel generators (and engines in vehicles) generate a lot of noise. The enclosure in which they are kept has necessary internal padding to absorb the sound. See if a code compliant enclosure can be installed for the inverter. These won't help if the noise is inherited by the other appliances also.

Comment: Back before flat-panels, CRT TVs had flyback transformers that could sometimes generate a similar high-pitched whine. I had a physics teacher who said the simplest solution was to squirt hot glue on it and this would dampen the squeal. I never tried it, and it requires opening up the unit you're working on, but it might be a solution. An internet image search will show lots of pictures of these transformers so you know what you're looking for.

Comment: did you resolve this, just had solar fitted and my 17 year old is saying exactly the same. Cheers Gary UK